# Python - Regarding lists,dictionarys and strings

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have put together a list called word_list:

```
print(word_list)

['deal', 5, 'price', 4, 'deal', 6, 'deal', '4', 'huge', '2', '$', '2', 'won', '3']
```

My goal with this list is to somehow combine the word with the value that follows it and when the work is done the list should look something like this:

```
print(worked_word_list)

['deal', 15, 'price', 4, 'huge', '2', '$', '2', 'won', '3']
```

I was thinking about first making it a dictionary, but I could really use some guidance on how to proceed from here.

Comment: How is `word_list` being generated? You have `'deal', 5`, `'deal', 6`, and `'deal', '4'` (with the last "value" being a string instead of an int), which is one problem. Why not just add together the values of all the identical "keys" when you're generating the list in the first place?

Comment: I think you cannot have keys with the same name in a dictionary. Consider using tuples.

Comment: I am using the extend function in a for loop.

Comment: Well, you really should be using a dictionary. Add logic in your for loop to check for the existence of a key, and if it's already there simply add the next item to the value, elsewise create a new key: value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

a = ['deal', 5, 'price', 4, 'deal', 6, 'deal', '4', 'huge', '2', '$', '2', 'won', '3']

d = defaultdict(int)
for x,y in zip(a[::2],a[1::2]):
    d[x] += int(y)

print list(chain.from_iterable((i,j) for i,j in d.items()))

[OUTPUT]
['huge', 2, 'price', 4, 'won', 3, '$', 2, 'deal', 15]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You might want to consider using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of the if/else.